# XPath - Selecting xml nodes with attributes with names that follow pattern

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to select all the nodes in an xml doc that have attributes with a certain naming pattern using XPath 1.0.

sample XML:

```
<Foo>
    <Bar id="1234">
        <Attributes foo_attrib1="foo" foo_attrib2="bar"/>
    </Bar>
    <Bar id="2345">
        <Attributes foo_attrib3="foobar"/>
    </Bar>
    <Bar id="3456"/>
</Foo>
```

The query i'm using is this:

```
/Foo/Bar/Attributes[starts-with(name(),'foo']
```

It seems like this should work, but I'm not getting any nodes returned with this query. Seems like this should also be a pretty simple query, so I'm sure I'm just messing something obvious up.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`name()` returns the name of the node you're currently examining, which in this case is the /Foo/Bar/Attributes node, so `name()` will return `"Attributes"`.

You want to look at the attributes of /Foo/Bar/Attributes, so you probably want something more like this:

```
/Foo/Bar/Attributes/@*[starts-with(name(), 'foo')]
```

Comment: Yes, I had eventually worked out the query you have here, but that actually selects the attributes of Attribute (as you mention) and I want to get all the Attribute nodes that have attribute names that start with 'foo'. So would I have to select all the nodes and then get their parents?

Comment: I guess I should just select all Attribute nodes and then loop through the attributes and see if any of them are named 'foo*'...?

Comment: @user1200340 Ah, I see. You want this: `/Foo/Bar/Attributes[@*[starts-with(name(), 'foo')]]`

Comment: that did it. Thanks Welbog!

Answer (score 0):

Because `name()` refers to the name of the node currently examining.

I'm not sure if you can match against an attribute 'which starts with..'

Comment: @DanielHaley Changed `element` to `node`.